# asp.net how to pass data from view to controller with an button

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm making an application in which i can switch from day to day using arrow buttons and see a type of chedule. in asp.net mvc.
(to be clear the left arrow moves a day back)
i'm just a student and not very advanced in mvc and razor and c#.

i'm trying to pass the data through a viewbag but the controller doesnt read the updated var.

the cshtml code

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Day", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

string CurrDay = ViewBag.CurrentDay.ToString();
@Html.Hidden("CurrentDay", CurrDay);

<div class="DayWrapper">

    <input type="submit" name="Butteun1" value="<" class="DayButtons" style="border-right-width: 2px;" onclick="getElementById('CurrentDay').innerHTML = '1'" />
    <a href="../HourMonth">
        <div class="AgendaDayButton">
            <p>  @ViewBag.CurrentDay.ToShortDateString() </p>
        </div>
    </a>
    <input type="submit" name="Butteun2" value=">" class="DayButtons" style="border-left-width: 2px;" onclick="getElementById('CurrentDay').innerHTML = '-1'" />
</div>
```

the controller code

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, int? customerIdFilter, int? projectIdFilter, string monthFilter, bool? totalsPerDay, int? CurrentEmployeeID, bool? missingDays, string Currentday)
    {
        totalsPerDay = GetCurrentTotalsPerDay(totalsPerDay);
        missingDays = GetCurrentMissingDays(missingDays);



        SetDefaultViewbag(sortOrder, monthFilter, totalsPerDay, CurrentEmployeeID, missingDays);

        string CurryDay = ViewBag.CurrentDay.ToString();

        if (CurryDay == "1")
        {
            Day.AddDays(1);
            return View(Day);
        }
        else if (CurryDay == "-1")
        {
            Day.AddDays(-1);
            return View(Day);
        }

        return View(GetData(sortOrder, customerIdFilter, projectIdFilter, totalsPerDay, CurrentEmployeeID, missingDays));
    }
```

Comment: So what **exactly** is the problem?

Comment: so the idea is, you press the button, 'currentday' changes to either "1" or "-1" (btw i just noticed both buttons change the var to 1)  and the date displayed will be changed, but when putting a break point at the if else statement 'currentday' hasn't been changed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I offer a simpler solution? I'm just going to address the issue you are having with dynamically changing the date on button press. Here is how I would approach this (Non-asynchronously, obviously an async solution would be better but for simplicity sake).

**A basic view that changes date dynamically:**

```
@model DateTime

<h1>SCHEDULE for @Model</h1>
<div class="btn btn-primary">
    @Html.ActionLink("Previous Day", "Index", new { datePassed = Model.AddDays(-1) })
</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary">
    @Html.ActionLink("Next Day", "Index", new { datePassed = Model.AddDays(1) })
</div>
```

**Corresponding Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(DateTime? datePassed = null)
    {
        if (datePassed == null) datePassed = DateTime.Today;
        return View(datePassed);
    }
}
```

Each time you click one of these buttons it should pass the new date incremented off of the current date either forward or backward back to the action on the controller and bring you back to the index page with the new date. This way you really shouldn't need to bother with the Viewbag at all.

Comment: This would have been the answer. but in my case, since I couldn't use 2 models, i've moved on to using cookies to store the data (if anyone would like to know how you can message me and ill show you). Thanks anyway!